# Cómo modifico las propiedades de un item en un listview en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Un saludo a todos, quisiera saber cómo puedo modificar las propiedades de un item en un listview, tengo ésta aplicación ABN que funciona muy bien, la cosa es que debo hacer que el primer item se parezca a la BBC.
[image: mi aplicación]

[image: así debe quedar]

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es agregar una vista diferente al inicio de tu `ListView` mediante [addHeaderView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) :

```
  listView.addHeaderView(myHeader);
```

Otra opción es inflar un layout diferente el adapter, cuando el item tiene el indice 0, que se considera el primer elemento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias, lo voy a probar.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, les cuento que nada, aún no me sale como debería, ya logré que se cargara el header al principio del listview, ahora el problema es que no llena sino que sólo aparece el diseño de layout vacío. acá dejo el código que estoy usando.

```
public void cargar_informacion(){

        listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        //ésta es la parte que le agregue
        View headerView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.header_view, null);

        listview.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);
        //*******************
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Éste es el header_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/flag"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="hace"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

y así es como me sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

tu puedes usar librerias externas para lograr esa lista, [te dejo una lista de librerias interesantes](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/List-Grid.md)

Sin embargo te recomiendo hacerlo manual. Debes de tener encuenta que los ListView son listas muy limitadas, si de verdad quieres jugar con las listas de una forma más profesional , debes usar RecyclerView , te da un control más dinamico de las listas.